# Form won't advance when using show function

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I have a form hidden on page load. When the user clicks on the "Enter Address" button it runs this function:

```
<script>
  function show(operation1) {
    document.getElementById('main_place').innerHTML = document.getElementById('operation1').innerHTML;
  }
</script>
```

However, doing it this way makes the form not advance when clicking "Next", and I don't know why. Everything should be the same using this script, but only the hidden form buttons works.

If you click on `Enter Address` the hidden form will show up on the top and will not advance through the fieldsets. What is going on here?

```js
function show(operation1) {
  document.getElementById('main_place').innerHTML = document.getElementById(operation1).innerHTML;
}

var interval = undefined;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.next').on('click', getNext);
  $('.previous').on('click', getPrev);
});

function getNext() {
  var $curr = $('fieldset:visible'),
    $next = ($curr.next().length) ? $curr.next() : $('fieldset').first();

  transition($curr, $next);
}

function getPrev() {
  var $curr = $('fieldset:visible'),
    $next = ($curr.prev().length) ? $curr.prev() : $('fieldset').last();
  transition($curr, $next);
}

function transition($curr, $next) {
  clearInterval(interval);
  $curr.hide();
  $next.show();

  $next.css('z-index', 2).fadeIn('fast', function() {
    $curr.hide().css('z-index', 0);
    $next.css('z-index', 1);
  });

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">


  <title>test</title>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/NewTow.css" type="text/css" />

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

</head>

<div id="main_place">

  <div class="swapcon1">

    text gets swapped here


  </div>

</div>





<div id=operation1 style="display:none;" class="">

  <h2>EASY 3-STEP FORM</h2>


  <form id="AUTO" method="post" action="" novalidate>

    <!-- fieldsets -->
    <fieldset>


      <div class="div1"><img src="images/step1.png" width="233" height="65"></div>

      <h3>CONTACT INFO</h3>
      <input type="hidden" name="token" value="3308f582b5dbc12f99a823c77be6cdc8" />
      <input type="hidden" name="miles" value="" />
      <div id="contact_name">FULL NAME: *<br>
        <input id="element_2_1" name="name" class="element text" size="15" maxlength="15" value="" type="text" placeholder="FULL NAME"></div>



      <div id="contact_phone">PHONE NUMBER: *<span id="req">Is Required</span><br>
        <input type='tel' name='phone' id="phone" class="phone" maxlength="15" placeholder="PHONE NUMBER" title="Phone Number Format:1(614)000-0000" pattern=" /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/" required />
      </div>


      <div id="contact_phone">EMAIL:<br>
        <input id="element_1" name="email" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS" />
      </div>




      <div class="button_holder">
        <input type="button" name="next" id="send" value="Next" class="next" />
      </div>



    </fieldset>




    <fieldset>
      <div class="div1"><img src="images/step2.png" width="233" height="65"></div>


      <h3>VEHICLE INFO</h3>

      <div id="contact_name">VEHICLE MAKE: *<br>
        <input id="element_2_1" name="make" class="element text" size="40" maxlength="40" value="" type="text" placeholder="VEHICLE MAKE"></div>


      <div id="contact_phone">VEHICLE MODEL: *<br>
        <input id="element_1" name="model" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="40" value="" placeholder="VEHICLE MODEL" /></div>

      <div id="contact_phone">YEAR*:<br>
        <input id="element_1" name="year" class="element text medium" type="number" maxlength="4" value="" placeholder="YEAR" />
      </div>


      <div id="contact_name">VIN NUMBER: <br>
        <input id="element_2_1" name="vin" class="element text" size="15" maxlength="17" value="" type="text" placeholder="VIN NUMBER"></div>


      <div id="contact_phone">INSURANCE COMPANY ( if applicable ):<br>
        <input id="element_1" name="insurance_company" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" placeholder="INSURANCE COMPANY" /></div>






      <div class="button_holder">
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
      </div>


    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <div class="div1"><img src="images/step3.png" width="233" height="65"></div>



      <div id="contact_message">MESSAGE:<br>
        <textarea id="element_3" name="message" class="element textarea medium" placeholder="START TYPING MESAGE HERE..."></textarea></div>





      <div class="button_holder">
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next" value="ALMOST DONE" />
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous" value="Previous" />
      </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <div class="div1"><img src="images/step4.png" width="233" height="65"></div>

      <h4>THANK YOU!</h4>
      <h5>Once you hit Submit a representative will be with you shortly. </h5>

      <div class="button_holder">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="SUBMIT" />
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />

      </div>

    </fieldset>



  </form>








</div>






</div>
<!--view_mas-->
</div>
<!--fade left-->
</div>
<!--towleft-->

<!--contact_slide1-->


<div class="towright">
  <div class="callout animation-element fadeinright">

    <div class="bthead"><span class="mainHEader1">where is your vechile?</span><br>
      <hr class="redline">
      <p>
        <?php echo $content1; ?>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="btloc">






      <button type="input" id="send" onclick="getLocation()" name="submi" class="button_text" value="" <?php echo $dis; ?>>
        <span id="boxcorner"></span>
        <div class="right2_button"><?php echo $deviceType; ?></div>
      </button>











    </div>
    <div class="bthr"><br>Or<br></div><br>



    <div class="btaddy">


      <button type="input" id="saveFor" onclick="show('operation1')" name="submi" class="button_text" value="">
        <span id="boxcorner"></span>
        <div class="right2_button"><span id="offset">Enter</span> Address</div>
      </button>




    </div><br>




    <div class="dtdis">Computers cannot use GPS correctly due do privacy laws and can only locate the server your connected too. </div>



  </div>
  <!--towright-->




</div>
<!--fadeinright-->



</div>
</div>



</body>

</html>
```

Full example (with CSS) at https://jsfiddle.net/83n01bwd/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I attach events to dynamic HTML elements with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/how-do-i-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that on page load (DOM ready) you're setting a click listener like

```
$('.next').on('click', getNext);
```

But then your DOM changes when you click "Enter Address", and the new `.next` doesn't have the event bound to it.

Per [How do I attach events to dynamic HTML elements with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/how-do-i-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements-with-jquery), what you want to do instead is to use `.on` (https://api.jquery.com/on/) on body, and then pass in the class you want to filter that event on. So change the event binding to

```
$('body').on('click', '.next', getNext);
```

Working example:

```js
function show(operation1) {
  document.getElementById('main_place').innerHTML = document.getElementById(operation1).innerHTML;
}

var interval = undefined;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('click', '.next', getNext);
  $('body').on('click', '.previous', getPrev);
});

function getNext() {
  var $curr = $('fieldset:visible'),
    $next = ($curr.next().length) ? $curr.next() : $('fieldset').first();

  transition($curr, $next);
}

function getPrev() {
  var $curr = $('fieldset:visible'),
    $next = ($curr.prev().length) ? $curr.prev() : $('fieldset').last();
  transition($curr, $next);
}

function transition($curr, $next) {
  clearInterval(interval);
  $curr.hide();
  $next.show();

  $next.css('z-index', 2).fadeIn('fast', function() {
    $curr.hide().css('z-index', 0);
    $next.css('z-index', 1);
  });

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">


  <title>test</title>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/NewTow.css" type="text/css" />

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

</head>

<div id="main_place">

  <div class="swapcon1">

    text gets swapped here


  </div>

</div>





<div id=operation1 style="display:none;" class="">

  <h2>EASY 3-STEP FORM</h2>


  <form id="AUTO" method="post" action="" novalidate>

    <!-- fieldsets -->
    <fieldset>


      <div class="div1"><img src="images/step1.png" width="233" height="65"></div>

      <h3>CONTACT INFO</h3>
      <input type="hidden" name="token" value="3308f582b5dbc12f99a823c77be6cdc8" />
      <input type="hidden" name="miles" value="" />
      <div id="contact_name">FULL NAME: *<br>
        <input id="element_2_1" name="name" class="element text" size="15" maxlength="15" value="" type="text" placeholder="FULL NAME"></div>



      <div id="contact_phone">PHONE NUMBER: *<span id="req">Is Required</span><br>
        <input type='tel' name='phone' id="phone" class="phone" maxlength="15" placeholder="PHONE NUMBER" title="Phone Number Format:1(614)000-0000" pattern=" /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/" required />
      </div>


      <div id="contact_phone">EMAIL:<br>
        <input id="element_1" name="email" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS" />
      </div>




      <div class="button_holder">
        <input type="button" name="next" id="send" value="Next" class="next" />
      </div>



    </fieldset>




    <fieldset>
      <div class="div1"><img src="images/step2.png" width="233" height="65"></div>


      <h3>VEHICLE INFO</h3>

      <div id="contact_name">VEHICLE MAKE: *<br>
        <input id="element_2_1" name="make" class="element text" size="40" maxlength="40" value="" type="text" placeholder="VEHICLE MAKE"></div>


      <div id="contact_phone">VEHICLE MODEL: *<br>
        <input id="element_1" name="model" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="40" value="" placeholder="VEHICLE MODEL" /></div>

      <div id="contact_phone">YEAR*:<br>
        <input id="element_1" name="year" class="element text medium" type="number" maxlength="4" value="" placeholder="YEAR" />
      </div>


      <div id="contact_name">VIN NUMBER: <br>
        <input id="element_2_1" name="vin" class="element text" size="15" maxlength="17" value="" type="text" placeholder="VIN NUMBER"></div>


      <div id="contact_phone">INSURANCE COMPANY ( if applicable ):<br>
        <input id="element_1" name="insurance_company" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" placeholder="INSURANCE COMPANY" /></div>






      <div class="button_holder">
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
      </div>


    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <div class="div1"><img src="images/step3.png" width="233" height="65"></div>



      <div id="contact_message">MESSAGE:<br>
        <textarea id="element_3" name="message" class="element textarea medium" placeholder="START TYPING MESAGE HERE..."></textarea></div>





      <div class="button_holder">
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next" value="ALMOST DONE" />
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous" value="Previous" />
      </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <div class="div1"><img src="images/step4.png" width="233" height="65"></div>

      <h4>THANK YOU!</h4>
      <h5>Once you hit Submit a representative will be with you shortly. </h5>

      <div class="button_holder">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="SUBMIT" />
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />

      </div>

    </fieldset>



  </form>








</div>






</div>
<!--view_mas-->
</div>
<!--fade left-->
</div>
<!--towleft-->

<!--contact_slide1-->


<div class="towright">
  <div class="callout animation-element fadeinright">

    <div class="bthead"><span class="mainHEader1">where is your vechile?</span><br>
      <hr class="redline">
      <p>
        <?php echo $content1; ?>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="btloc">






      <button type="input" id="send" onclick="getLocation()" name="submi" class="button_text" value="" <?php echo $dis; ?>>
        <span id="boxcorner"></span>
        <div class="right2_button"><?php echo $deviceType; ?></div>
      </button>











    </div>
    <div class="bthr"><br>Or<br></div><br>



    <div class="btaddy">


      <button type="input" id="saveFor" onclick="show('operation1')" name="submi" class="button_text" value="">
        <span id="boxcorner"></span>
        <div class="right2_button"><span id="offset">Enter</span> Address</div>
      </button>




    </div><br>




    <div class="dtdis">Computers cannot use GPS correctly due do privacy laws and can only locate the server your connected too. </div>



  </div>
  <!--towright-->




</div>
<!--fadeinright-->



</div>
</div>



</body>

</html>
```

Full working example at https://jsfiddle.net/vsp72aqd/